# Can Russell's paradox be circumvented by set classification?

Tags: set-theory

I'm a first semester student of computer science, and I've probably thought a bit too much about some paradoxes that were proven in the semester.

Can't you just avoid Russell's paradox for sets, if you just define different set spaces? Instead of thinking of all sets as equal, you could use a word like meta-set of n-th degree to classify sets, and make statements about those classes of sets. Meta sets of 0-th degree would only contain non-set elements, while any set containing a set of n-th degree, is a set of "n+1"-th degree.

Then you can construct the meta-set of all "smaller than or equal to n"-th degree meta-sets, which would automatically not contain itself, because it's degree is n+1, and could even iteratively go to infinity without paradox, or is there some logical problem with that?

Does something like this exist already and what is it called?

Comment: Mathematicians do this. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(set_theory)

Comment: You've rediscovered a version of (simple) type theory.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe

Comment: See Willard Van Orman Quine, [*On the Theory of Types*, JSL (1938)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2267776)

Comment: See also [stratification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratification_(mathematics)).